# Mysql is not connecting with php in wamp server.

Tags: php

require(../connect_db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\php\require.php on line 10 in wamp server. This is my first time trying to connect to mysql with php. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: i am using wamp server.

Comment: '../connect_db.php' means 'go one directory up and open the file connect_db.php'. You should point the path to the file correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a relative path (`../connect_db.php`).

You need to take into consideration that the path is not relative to the file where the require is used, but to the file that is run.

So, if you have your main file `index.php`, you could have the following:

```
// index.php
include('config/config.php');

// config/config.php
include('config/db/connect.php'); // relative to index.php folder
include('db/connect.php') // WON'T WORK
```

The directory structure would be:

```
index.php
config/
    config.php
    db/
        connect.php
```

Answer (score 0):

> failed to open stream: **No such file or directory**

Your path is incorrect.

For example, your code `require('../connect_db.php');` does the following;

- Go up one directory
- Require `connect_db.php`

If we have the following tree structure, your code will work

```
/wamp/
 www/
    connect_db.php
   php/
     require.php
```

I would suggest moving `connect_db.php` into `php/` and altering your require to become `require('connect_db.php');`. Or, paste your tree structure, and we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: really?  i have tried many times but still the error is showing up.

Comment: Really. Paste your file tree/directory structure in your original post.

Comment: can you be little detail about how to paste the tree directory structure? please...

Comment: Thanks dude. i just pasted the file path and it worked. Wow. its all about trial and error. C:\wamp\www\php. like this. thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that connect_db.php file exists in C:\wamp\www dir. 
Also check folder permissions on that directory (I don't know which user uses wamp, but try first to give permissions to all users and then filter a little more).

Answer (score 0):

be sure to check these following reasons:

- file exists
- file location is correct ( '../file') means upper location